# How to avoid infinite loop when using try/catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this code

```
public void askUserForStrategy(){

    try{

        System.out.println("What strategy do you want to use?\n");
        System.out.println("1 = Math.random\t     2 = System time\t "
        + "3 = Sum of Math.random and System time");

        int strategy = sc.nextInt();

        selectStrategy(strategy);

    }

    catch(InputMismatchException Exception){

        System.out.println("That is not an integer. Try again.\n");
        askUserForStrategy();

    }

}
```

What I want it to do is basically ask the user to type in an integer, and in case the user the users types a String for example, catch that exception and start the method again (ask the user to type in an integer value). But the method loops when the user types in a String.

Comment: Do not use `try-catch` for your program flow. It should only handle unrecoverable exceptions; not re-try the same process.

Answer (score 4):

When `nextInt()` throws an exception, the `Scanner` object tries to use the same string on the next call.

Try allocating a new `Scanner` Object within the `try`. Or try to call `nextLine()` within the `catch`, so you will discard the illegal line.

Please note that this method is not good, because after too many illegal inputs (very many, but the ideal is to have infinite tries) a stack overflow will occur.

I suggest you to use a `do-while` and `return` at the end of the `try` body.

Comment: thanks! I just moved the scanner object within the method and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void askUserForStrategy() {

 for(int i=0; i<1; ++i) {
  try{

    System.out.println("What strategy do you want to use?\n");
    System.out.println("1 = Math.random\t     2 = System time\t "
    + "3 = Sum of Math.random and System time");

    int strategy = sc.nextInt();

    selectStrategy(strategy);
    break;  //break loop when there is no error
  }

  catch(InputMismatchException Exception){

    System.out.println("That is not an integer. Try again.\n");
    //askUserForStrategy();
    continue; //for clarity

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this

```
public void askUserForStrategy(){
Boolean loopFlag = true;
while(loopFlag) {
try{

    System.out.println("What strategy do you want to use?\n");
    System.out.println("1 = Math.random\t     2 = System time\t "
    + "3 = Sum of Math.random and System time");

    int strategy = sc.nextInt();
    Integer.parseInt(strategy);
    loopFlag  = false;
    selectStrategy(strategy);
}

catch(Exception e){

    //Parse has failed due to wrong input value, But loop will continue

}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be you are looking for..

```
public void askUserForStrategy() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("What strategy do you want to use?\n");
                System.out.println("1 = Math.random\t     2 = System time\t " + "3 = Sum of Math.random and System time");

                int strategy = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Selected strategy : " +strategy);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is not an integer. Try again.\n");
                continue;
            }
        }
        // selectStrategy(strategy);
    }
```

If user selects String, then again it will ask for options..

If user selects Integer, then it will take user selected strategy option and continue the program flow.. (Means come out of the while loop with the help of break and then calling selectStrategy method)

Thanks